# ASP.NET - catch sql duplicate exception

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, key

I need a help with a sql exceptin of inserting duplicate key into database.
I cause the exception deliberatly to not insert the duplicit record into database.

In code behind I have this code:

```vb
Protected Sub SqlDataSource3_Inserting(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)
    Try

    Catch ex As SqlException

    End Try
End Sub
```

But I don't know what to write into the `Try...Catch` block. I just want to display a MessageBox with text *You are already a member of this group.* insted of error page.

This is my server code:

```xml
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" OnInserted="SqlDataSource3_Inserted" OnInserting="SqlDataSource3_Inserting" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MotWebConnectionString %>" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [GroupMembers] ([UserName], [GroupId]) VALUES (@UserName, @GroupId)" >

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" OnInserted="SqlDataSource3_Inserted" OnInserting="SqlDataSource3_Inserting" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MotWebConnectionString %>" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [GroupMembers] ([UserName], [GroupId]) VALUES (@UserName, @GroupId)" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception will not be raised in the event handler; instead you should do something like:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource3_Inserted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
   If e.Exception IsNot Nothing Then
      ' Handle exception here
      ' Prevent exception from being re-thrown
      e.ExceptionHandled = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer, but I have a litte problem with your code. In part If e.exception IsNot Nothing.... the e.exception is blue underlined with a text: Exception is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs. The same it is with e.ExceptionHandled

Comment: Sorry, I should've changed the handler to handle the Inserted event rather than Inserting. I have updated my answer.

Comment: But even when I changed it to handle the inserted event, there is still the text - exception is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs

Comment: You have to change the type of the `e` argument too: for the `Inserted` event handler, the type is `SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs`, not `SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs`